# Problems installing Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1

I have been trying to install Visual Studio 2010 Professional on my Windows 8.1 laptop and I am having problems. It seems to install and when I look at the applications list I see everything has installed except the Visual Studio 2010 (`devenv.exe`) application itself. Has anyone had this problem and found a solution for it? I have checked that .NET 2.0, 3.x and 4.x are all installed on the machine and active. The installer shows that it is installing the application but when it's completed the application is no where to be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me, because I had SQL Server Data Tools installed, causing the shortcut to be named "sql server Data Tools". Try looking up the executable in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` and manually creating the shortcut on the start screen:

[image]

Be sure to install the updates as well:

- [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
- [Visual Studio 2010 GDR for Team Foundation Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)
- [Visual Studio 2010 Compatibility Update for Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34677)

For an up to date list of patches and service packs see:

- https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/